# How to stop log custom exception, show it on the front end only

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql

While I used rest api there was a feature not to write custom exceptions (e. g. MissingQuetyParameter) to the logs.
For customize graphql exceptions I'm using implementation of the `GraphQLErrorHandler` interface:

```
public class CustomGraphQlErrorHandler implements GraphQLErrorHandler {

    @Override
    public List<GraphQLError> processErrors(List<GraphQLError> errors) {
        return errors.stream()
                .map(err -> new GenericGraphQLError(err.getMessage()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Is there is some flag to say logger to stop log custom errors to the server logs as it is custom issues?

Comment: I am also running into the same issue